# How to plot a specific range of values from a text file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file contain values as:

```
0.00   -10.742    10.7888  6.33455
1.00   -17.75391  10.0000  4.66778
4.00   -19.62891  15.9999  4.232323
20.00  -20.7641   18.6666  3.99999
23.00  -34.2300   2.7777   2.00000
50.00  -50.000    1.87878  2.77778
65.88   -22.5000  2.99999  1.45555
78.00   -30.000   1.55555  2.45667
86.00   -37.7900  2.55556  7.55679
90.00   -45.00000 13.6667  2.677888
```

I wish to plot only a range of values from a text file after a time interval another set of values to be plotted.
For example:
First I wish to plot only[0 to 50]:

```
0.00   -10.742
1.00   -17.75391
4.00   -19.62891
20.00  -20.7641
23.00  -34.2300
50.00  -50.000
```

After a time interval( say 10s) I wish to plot next set of values ie:

```
65.88   -22.5000
78.00   -30.000
86.00   -37.7900
90.00   -45.00000
```

Looking forward to show this as a slideshow.

What I have tried is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
fileName=input("Enter Input File Name: ")
f1=open(fileName,'r')
style.use('ggplot')
x1,y1=np.loadtxt(fileName,unpack=True, usecols=(0,1));
plt.plot(x1,y1,'r')
plt.plot
plt.title('example1')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.grid(True,color='k')
plt.show()
```

I wish to show this as a slideshow. I will be thankful if someone helps me out there.

Comment: Why not create all the plots as images. Then load and show the images one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and iterate over the rows and display them. Say you have 100 rows of data and you want to display 25 rows at a time.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('/path/to/data/file')

m = np.size(data, 0) # Getting total no of rows
n = np.size(data, 1) # Getting total no of columns

x = data[:, 0].reshape(m, 1) # X data 
y = data[:, 1].reshape(m, 1) # Y data

iters = m // 4
current_iter = 0
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan']

for i in range(3):
    plt.scatter(x[current_iter:current_iter+iters, :], y[current_iter:current_iter+iters, :], color=colors[i])
    plt.title('example1')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Values')
    plt.pause(10)
    plt.clf()
    current_iter = current_iter + iters
```

We need to calculate the number of `iterations`. This is done by `iters = m // 4`. Now you loop through the number of iterations using `for`. To pause and plot the graph, use `plt.pause(10)` which displays the graph for 10 seconds(you can set your time for your convenience). Then clear it using `plot.clf()`. This continues until the end of the `loop`.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: y = data[:, 1].reshape(m, 1);

Comment: y = data[:, 1].reshape(m, 1); Cannot reshape array of size 9 to shape(2,1). I have edited my requirement. As I am new to matplotlib, I don't know how to fix this.Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Like I did, retrieve your `X data` and `Y data` from the entire `dataset` and reshape it according to your need. You can get the total no of rows like I am doing in the code.

Comment: It is not appearing as a slideshow. First I wish to plot a upto 50 .Then after a time interval(10s). I wish plot from 50 to 100 then another likewise.I  wish to show this as a slideshow. Please help me to acheive this. Your code only plot upto 1.

Comment: My code will automatically plot the graph of 25-row values every ten seconds. You can use a pause-resume mechanism to make it work as a slideshow.

Comment: .How to use pause resume mechanism to make it work as a slideshow. Please help with a code.

Comment: At the start of every loop add `input('')`. So now when you hit enter, the graph will come up and display for 10 seconds. When you hit enter again, the second graph will come up.

Comment: @Bin If you like my answer please upvote it. Thank you!

Comment: This code is  showing figure after reading the end of file also.How to stop showing figure after the end of file.The  figure should close automatically after finish reading data from file. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: @Bin The code is already written in such a way that it closes the figure at the end of the file. If it doesn't work, try adding `plt.clf()` at the end.

Comment: I have updated my requirement. I need to emebed my code to pyqt5.  Currently it is not showing as a slideshow, only first set of data works. I wish to plot the whole data as a slideshow with a specific interval. Please help to fix this.